# Automatically generate source files for Xcode projects

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm currently in a slightly complicated situation where I need to automatically generate a source file for each Mach-O object file compiled from the human-written source files in the project. I want Xcode to do the following:

1. Compile the initial source files in the project
2. Run a script which parses the Mach-O objects obtained in step 1 and generate a new source file for each of them
3. Compile the newly generated source to objects
4. Link all objects together

I know that Xcode allows developers to add hooks when processing certain kinds of files in the build process. My problem is that if I ask Xcode to hook Mach-O object files, the build process goes into a recursion that never terminates because the hook will run at step 3 as well. Is there a way to accomplish what I described above in Xcode?